# SVD on a symbolic matrix on Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to calculate the SVD on this symbolic matrix using Matlab

```
0 2 3 4*a 5*a
6 7 1 8*a 9*a
```

using the following code:

```
syms a
M = [0 2 3 4*a 5*a ; 6 7 1 8*a 9*a]
s = svd(M)
```

It's working, and i can get the singular values, but using the following code I can get the orthogonal matrices.

```
[U,S,V] = svd(M)
```

I get this error:

> Error using sym/svd (line 85)
>   Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers.

How can i deal with that?

Comment: It just looks like `svd` does not accept non-numeric inputs. try doing: `syms a real`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Just tried it. Same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/svd.html) (emphasis mine):

> [U,S,V] = svd(A) returns numeric unitary matrices U and V with the columns containing the singular vectors, and a diagonal matrix S containing the singular values. The matrices satisfy the condition A = U*S*V', where V' is the Hermitian transpose (the complex conjugate transpose) of V. The singular vector computation uses variable-precision arithmetic. **svd does not compute symbolic singular vectors. Therefore, the input matrix A must be convertible to floating-point numbers. For example, it can be a matrix of symbolic numbers.**

So simply, you cant. It's not supported.